# Adding Elements in an existing XML using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add elements into an existing XML document using XDocument. I am getting a null reference exception because it is not finding the element that I want to append.

Here is the code:

```
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Documents\Test.xml");
     XElement root = new XElement("SystemMonitor");
     doc.Element("DewesoftSetup").Add(root);
   
     doc.Save(@"C:\Documents\Test.xml");
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DewesoftXML>
  <System Name="Local">
    <SysInfo>
    </SysInfo>
    <DewesoftSetup>
    </DewesoftSetup>
 </System>
</DewesoftXML>
```

I am trying to add an child element to DewesoftSetup.

Heres the error:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) returned null.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Element` method finds a *direct* child element. In your case, you're looking for `DewesoftSetup`, which is under `System` which itself is under `DewesoftXML` (which is the root element). There are two options here:

First, you could use `Element` twice - once to get from the root to `System`, then again to get from `System` to `DewesoftSetup`:

```cs
doc.Root.Element("System").Element("DewesoftSetup").Add(root);
```

Alternatively, you could use `Descendants` to find all *descendants* called `DewesoftSetup`, and just take the first of them:

```cs
doc.Descendants("DewesoftSetup").First().Add(root);
```

Personally I'd use the first approach, but the second can be useful if the element can occur in multiple different places.

As an aside, I would change the name of your `root` variable, as it makes it sound like you expect it to be the root element, which it isn't.

Comment: Ahh Thank you! I knew I was missing something simple